# Is there a way to find a Removed Keyvault by it's tags

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to find the KeyVaultname of my removed keyvault (by softdelete) by its specifics tags.

This is the keyvault I need to find:

[KeyVault In Removed State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muIVS.png)

Unfortunately the command to find the tags for a keyvault by below cmd doesn't work for a Keyvault which is in a Removed state. (It works when the KeyVault is not removed)

```
(Get-AzKeyvault -InRemovedState -tag @{"RemovalDate" = "14-04-2022"})
```

Gives the following error:

```
Get-AzKeyVault : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-AzKeyvault -InRemovedState -tag @{"RemovalDate" = "14-04-2022"})
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzKeyVault], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.GetAzureKeyVault
```

I tried as well:

```
(Get-AzKeyvault -InRemovedState | Where-Object {$_.Tag["RemovalDate"] -eq "14-04-2022"})
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:49
+ ... RemovedState | Where-Object {$_.Tag['RemovalDate'] -eq '14-04-2022'})
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at `'Deletion Date'` or `'Scheduled Purge Date'` instead? Seems your `.Tags` property is empty..

Answer (score 0):

You were close, just needed to pipe results of the `Get-AzKeyVault`, then query it like any other object.

First, find out the object types that are returned.

```
Get-AzKeyVault -InRemovedState | get-member
```

This displays the column names and object type. Now write your query appropriately.

```
Get-AzKeyVault -InRemovedState | 
    select VaultName, Tags |
        where {$_.Tags["RemovalDate"] -eq "14-04-2022"}
```